# replace unix path inside a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a sql file of a wordpress database. I am moving to another server which the document root is different.

The old document root was `/home/saeid/public_html`

The new document root is  `/home/saeid/www/domain.com/html`

I want to replace all the occurrences of old path with new path.

I have seen this example which replaces foo with bar...but as I want to replace path which itself has "/" characters in it...I am not sure if it would the job. `sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' filename`

Comment: maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109666/117549 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use a different delimiter:

```
sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' filename
```

So, in your case:

```
sed -i 's|/home/saeid/public_html|/home/saeid/www/domain.com/html|g' file
```

This is mentioned in [`info sed`](http://www.manpagez.com/info/sed/sed-4.2.2/sed_8.php#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> The syntax of the s (as in substitute) command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’. The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character **(or whatever other character is used in its stead)** can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.